# Auto Incrementing Number Values in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to re-number over 30,000 rows in excel and am looking for a way to do this through an embedded excel function.

I have two columns, the original BuildingCount and the Test column. In the BuildingCount column, I have inconsistent count that needs to be consecutive 1,2,3 numbers in order to run a macros. However, the numbers are not always consecutive. I have been writing different variations of excel functions. The below is the output for =IF(A2>1),A2+1,1)

```
+----+---------------+------------+
|    |       A       |     B      |  
+----+---------------+------------+
|  1 | BuildingCount | TestColumn |  
|  2 | 1             | #VALUE!    |  
|  3 | 2             | 1          |  
|  4 | 3             | 3          |  
|  5 | 5             | 4          |  
|  6 | 6             | 6          |  
|  7 | 9             | 7          |  
|  8 | 1             | 10         |  
|  9 | 2             | 1          |  
| 10 | 3             | 3          |  
| 11 | 4             | 4          |  
| 12 | 5             | 5          |  
+----+---------------+------------+
```

Ideally, the output would be the following:

```
+----+---------------+------------+
|    |       A       |     B      |  
+----+---------------+------------+
|  1 | BuildingCount | TestColumn |  
|  2 | 1             | 1          |  
|  3 | 2             | 2          |  
|  4 | 3             | 3          |  
|  5 | 5             | 4          |  
|  6 | 6             | 5          |  
|  7 | 7             | 6          |  
|  8 | 1             | 1          |  
|  9 | 2             | 2          |  
| 10 | 3             | 3          |  
| 11 | 4             | 4          |  
| 12 | 5             | 5          |  
+----+---------------+------------+
```

Any ideas would be very welcomed.

Comment: Does it always reset on `1` or just whenever the count is less than the one above?

Comment: You have an extra closing bracket in the middle of `=IF(A2>1),A2+1,1)`

Comment: @scottcraner It should be resetting at 1. Also, the test column is only an added column to get the calculation. My intention would then be to copy the results of column B into column A, replacing the nonconsecutive numbers for the macros to run successfully (essentially column B would be deleted once the numbers are fixed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=IF(ROW()=2,1,IF(A2>A1,B1+1,1))
```

And dragged down

Comment: Hi @jvdv, the above did the trick! Thanks so much, literally saved me a lot of time of manual work... which is usually what I have done in the past.